# Access Violation / Stack Overflow in 3rd party Library used by Web Service

Tags: web-services, dll, c++-cli

I have a web service which uses a C++/CLI DLL that I created to perform certain operations. Now, the C++/CLI DLL calls a function from a third party DLL which  throws an exception **ONLY** when it is used via the web service. If it is used in a standalone application, the process is smooth. I create a mini dump any time the exception occurs, which can be either an access violation or stack overflow. From looking at the call stack (seen below), I notice that the exception is thrown by a `std::_Init_locks::operator=` function. I don't completely understand its responsibility or why the exception occurs when it is called, hence my plea for assistance. So my question is, why do I only get an exception when this DLL is being called via a web service and why does it occur at this point?

(Project specifications: .NET 4.0 for web service and C++/CLI DLL)

Thanks in advance.

**Stack trace:**

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`019f3a38 00000000`1894e332 frsdk_9_0_0!std::_Init_locks::operator=+0x3cf
00000000`019f3a50 00000000`18945d09 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::CaptureDeviceBody::operator=+0x6152
00000000`019f3a90 00000000`1894620d frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0xc55b9
00000000`01a38610 00000000`18946380 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0xc5abd
00000000`01a387b0 00000000`18946567 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0xc5c30
00000000`01a38820 00000000`188818e3 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0xc5e17
00000000`01a38860 00000000`1888e0a9 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0x1193
00000000`01a38950 00000000`188a02b4 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0xd959
00000000`01a38b00 00000000`1884e6a5 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Box::endy+0x1fb64
00000000`01a38c70 00000000`1882fb34 frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::CaptureDeviceBody::gainRange+0x4e255
00000000`01a38d80 00000000`187af3ab frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::CaptureDeviceBody::gainRange+0x2f6e4
00000000`01a3a280 00000000`180fc62a frsdk_9_0_0!FRsdk::Enrollment::Processor::process+0x174b
00000000`01a3a3c0 00000000`180f1227 BioEngine!BioAlgos::Encode+0x24a 
00000000`01a3a6d0 00000000`180f1dab BioEngine!BioAlgos::EncodeAndWriteTemplate+0x27 
00000000`01a3a740 00000000`18027365 BioEngine!BioAlgos::EnrollSubject+0x30b 
00000000`01a3ab70 00000000`180aecb0 BioEngine!FRE::Enroll+0x185 
00000000`01a3ad40 00000000`1811be4b BioEngine!RecogProcessor::Enroll+0x290 
00000000`01a3aec0 000007fe`96c7dfe9 BioEngine!RecogProcessor_Enroll+0x16b 
00000000`01a3b350 000007fe`96c7db2f 0x000007fe`96c7dfe9
00000000`01a3b430 000007fe`96c78d05 0x000007fe`96c7db2f
00000000`01a3b510 000007fe`96c77698 0x000007fe`96c78d05
00000000`01a3bb30 000007fe`96c76117 0x000007fe`96c77698
00000000`01a3c0b0 000007fe`96c7269d 0x000007fe`96c76117
00000000`01a3c6f0 000007fe`96c7cc1d 0x000007fe`96c7269d
00000000`01a3d800 000007fe`96c7c017 0x000007fe`96c7cc1d
00000000`01a3dc50 000007fe`96c7bd6e 0x000007fe`96c7c017
00000000`01a3dcd0 000007fe`96d79599 0x000007fe`96c7bd6e
00000000`01a3dd60 000007fe`f2161663 0x000007fe`96d79599
00000000`01a3dde0 000007fe`f215db45 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x631663
00000000`01a3dfc0 000007fe`f215d330 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x62db45
00000000`01a3e370 000007fe`f215c9cb System_ServiceModel_ni+0x62d330
00000000`01a3e420 000007fe`f215b3de System_ServiceModel_ni+0x62c9cb
00000000`01a3e600 000007fe`f215a8f7 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x62b3de
00000000`01a3e6c0 000007fe`f2158ca3 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x62a8f7
00000000`01a3eaa0 000007fe`f21587cb System_ServiceModel_ni+0x628ca3
00000000`01a3eb20 000007fe`f19ed1a2 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x6287cb
00000000`01a3eb80 000007fe`f19e7aaa System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4d1a2
00000000`01a3ebd0 000007fe`f19ed3d1 System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x47aaa
00000000`01a3ec80 000007fe`f19eccdc System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4d3d1
00000000`01a3ecd0 000007fe`f19ec8ae System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4ccdc
00000000`01a3ee40 000007fe`f2185232 System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4c8ae
00000000`01a3eeb0 000007fe`f2184b9f System_ServiceModel_ni+0x655232
00000000`01a3ef10 000007fe`f2184a0a System_ServiceModel_ni+0x654b9f
00000000`01a3ef90 000007fe`f19eb3d5 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x654a0a
00000000`01a3efc0 000007fe`f19ed1a2 System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4b3d5
00000000`01a3f040 000007fe`f19e7aaa System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4d1a2
00000000`01a3f090 000007fe`f218426b System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x47aaa
00000000`01a3f140 000007fe`f19ed1a2 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x65426b
00000000`01a3f1b0 000007fe`ed1feece System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+0x4d1a2
00000000`01a3f200 000007fe`ed1bb917 System_Web_ni+0xb8eece
00000000`01a3f2f0 000007fe`ed1f1ef0 System_Web_ni+0xb4b917
00000000`01a3f330 000007fe`ed0baac4 System_Web_ni+0xb81ef0
00000000`01a3f390 000007fe`f62bac23 System_Web_ni+0xa4aac4
00000000`01a3f3f0 000007fe`f62d49ec clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+0x43
00000000`01a3f430 000007fe`f62c94ae clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+0x54
00000000`01a3f480 000007fe`f62d4975 clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x12e
00000000`01a3f650 000007fe`f62babcd clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+0x91
00000000`01a3f6d0 000007fe`eb400326 clr!UMThunkStub+0x26d
00000000`01a3f760 000007fe`eb3f1bfe webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::DoWork+0x293
00000000`01a3f7c0 000007fe`ef31ba3c webengine4!RequestDoWork+0x34e
00000000`01a3f860 000007fe`ef3146a4 iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork+0x314
00000000`01a3f8a0 000007fe`ef31a775 iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal+0x174
00000000`01a3f990 000007fe`ef315a03 iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules+0x25
00000000`01a3f9e0 000007fe`ef311741 iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoWork+0x34d
00000000`01a3fd00 000007fe`f8e710b2 iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::OnIoCompletion+0x81
00000000`01a3fd30 000007fe`f8e7109c w3dt!UL_NATIVE_REQUEST::DoWork+0x22b
00000000`01a3fd90 000007fe`f95e1fba w3dt!OverlappedCompletionRoutine+0x1c
00000000`01a3fdc0 000007fe`f95e2024 w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+0x7a
00000000`01a3fe10 000007fe`f95e20a1 w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+0x34
00000000`01a3fe40 00000000`76e55a4d w3tp!THREAD_MANAGER::ThreadManagerThread+0x61
00000000`01a3fe70 00000000`7708b831 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`01a3fea0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Comment: I'd start by using something like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to see what that DLL is doing. Problems like this are usually security-related (especially if your web service runs under the restricted NetworkService account), so if the DLL is failing to access a system resource then ProcMon may tell you where it's choking.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't put too much stock in that stack trace--it may be inaccurate unless you have PDBs for the DLL(s) in question.

Comment: @MarkWaterman Yeah, I don't think those are the correct functions for the third party DLL because I'm not trying to capture images from a camera. Do you have any idea what `std::_Init_locks` is responsible for?

Comment: It looks like _Init_locks is an internal class that's responsible for initializing the underlying Win32 synchronization primitives that are used by the MS C/C++ runtime libraries. I don't see any operator overloads on it, so I'd be surprised if it's causing the problem. Unless the third-party DLL vendor is willing to analyze that minidump for you (or provide you with PDBs), I'd give up on trying to make sense of that stack trace.

Comment: @MarkWaterman Thanks. I don't think the library owners would want to divulge that information, so I'm stuck with this problem. However, I don't see this problem with a recent release of their software, so I'll mark this issue as unsolved and just use the new release instead as a work around. I spent a couple of weeks trying to figure out why this only occurred with web services to no avail.

Comment: @Duncs There are many functions from the Windows API that are not allowed to be called from a Windows Service (as it is the case for IIS) on Windows 7/Server 2008 and later, probably you are using a version of the library that is just too old and updating it is the proper solution (and not a workaround).

Comment: @yms I agree, it is the accepted solution and not a workaround. However, the version of the library I was using was only released a couple of months ago. Their newer version was just released literally a few days ago. Thankfully, it takes care of the issue.

Comment: @Duncs then you just encountered a bug, it happens to all of us. You should feel lucky that it has been resolved already, it could be much worse.

Comment: @yms Because I'm curious by nature, I still want to know the cause of the exception. I'm also practical by nature, so I have to move on and take it as a loss.